# Remove rows automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a big Excel file and want to remove all but one of each 200 consecutive rows. If I have a file with 1,000 rows to keep only five.

How might I achieve this in a single operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column with:

```
=ROW()=FLOOR(ROW(),200)
```

in Row1 and copy down to suit. Filter that to select `FALSE` and delete visible.

For Filter, select the column then go to DATA > Sort & Filter and click on Filter (the funnel). A small downward pointing arrow should appear to the right of the cell in Row1. Click it, uncheck (Select All) and check FALSE, OK.

Then click on the arrow extreme top left (intersect of the Row and Column Headings). Right click in the highlighted area and click on Delete. If you see no Row and Column Headings, go to VIEW > Show and check Headings.

Comment: your answer was perfect. sorry for funny question but i did not use excel too much. can you just give me a little hint about your last part? how should i filter and delete visible?